# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) when using get.dart method

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

```
import 'package:calendar_app/consts/routes.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/controller/task_controller.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/models/task.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/services/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/widgets/task_tile.dart';
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as devtools show log;
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DateTime _selectDate = DateTime.now();
  final _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());
  var notif;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notif = Notif();
    notif.initializeNotification();
    notif.requestIOSPermissions();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 202, 202),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50, 20, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          // Date
                          DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          // Today
                          'Today',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      // Add Task
                      label: '+ Add Task',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                          addTaskRoute,
                          // (route) => false,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                DatePicker(
                  // Calendar
                  DateTime.now(),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 80,
                  initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                  selectionColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 12, 103, 179),
                  selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
                  dateTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  dayTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  monthTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  onDateChange: (date) {},
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _showTasks(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _showTasks() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Obx(
        () {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              devtools.log(_taskController.taskList.length.toString());
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            devtools.log('tapped');
                            _showBottomSheet(
                              context,
                              _taskController.taskList[index],
                            );
                          },
                          child: TaskTile(
                            _taskController.taskList[index],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Task task) {
    Get.bottomSheet(
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
        height: task.isCompleted == 1
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25
            : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
        color: Colors.white,
        ),
    );
  }

  _bottomSheetButton({
    required String label,
    required Function()? onTap,
    required Color color,
    bool isClose = false,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        height: 55,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2,
            color: isClose == true ? Colors.red : color,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: isClose == true ? Colors.red : color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm clicking on container it throwing an exception saying:

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

I didn't use any null operators in here
Is this a problem with Get.bottomsheet method or what?<br?
Exception showing _showBottomSheet has something wrong I mean null operator or whatever
Can you please help me go through this?

Comment: In which line is it showing this error

Answer (score 0):

in your method _showBottomSheet, Task is required variable.

_taskController.taskList[index] -> this is probably null, you should debug this.

In your method, you can set Task as optional, like this: Task? task, and call your method like this:

_showBottomSheet(
context,
_taskController.taskList?[index],
);

and then:

```
  _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Task? task) {
    Get.bottomSheet(
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
        height: task?.isCompleted == 1
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25
            : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
        color: Colors.white,
        ),
    );
  }
```